# Can't change default language of an assembly in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, culture

My application supports three languages: en, es, and fr.  When I build my (clean, from a template) UWP application, I get the message:

```
warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'en,es,fr' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language.
```

So then I go into the manifest and change the default language from en-US to en-GB and when I recompile I get:

```
warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'en,es,fr' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-GB,en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language.
```

What gives?  How do I replace the default language in a UWP application so that it doesn't try to find en-US resources?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this has anything to do with *assembly* language as in "language that is turned into machine code by an assembler" now, does it? You might want to change the title into something less ambiguos.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the warning, you have to update the language in 2 places:

- Default language in appxmanifest, which gets saved in the csproj file as `<DefaultLanguage>en-GB</DefaultLanguage>`
- Neutral assembly language, which is saved in the AssemblyInfo file as `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-GB")]` and can also be changed through the project's properties > assembly information.

[image: Assemly information]

Next to that, you have to use a full language qualifier (en-US, en-GB, ...) as the default language, as 'en' gets just redirected to en-US as the default language. Other languages can be language-only qualifiers (fr).

Note that specifying your assets with a full qualifier doesn't break other regional languages from using these resources.

> Windows does cross regional matching. For example, en-US matches en-US, then en, and then en-*.

Imho it's even better to use the full qualifier as your translation is done in one of the regional languages (quite often the main region), so fr-FR is more accurate to tag your resource file than just fr.

Comment: >>Next to that, you have to use a full language qualifier (en-US, en-GB, ...) as the default language, as 'en' gets just redirected to en-US as the default language. Other languages can be language-only qualifiers (fr).  I agree that this is how it behaves, but I don't understand why that makes sense.  Why am I forced to select en-US when I want to target all English speaking cultures?

Comment: The localization you provide (behavior vs behaviour) is either en-US or en-GB, not just 'en'. But it doesn't matter, as the application will fall back to the language your provided (see the quoted block).