# Resource not found for default language ''

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm having the problem that I cannot fix this warning:

> GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found
>   for language(s) 'en-us,...' but no resources found for default
>   language(s): ''. Change the default language or qualify resources with
>   the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
>   [x.csproj]

I have tried this [Can't change default language of an assembly in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619115/cant-change-default-language-of-an-assembly-in-visual-studio-2017), but it did not work.

The default language is set in the x.csproj as follows `<DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>`. This is located in the first property block of the csproj. I also tried setting the language in the "AssemblyInfo.cs" of project x but it did not work either.

The strange thing is, this problem is only present on my feature branch, not in the development branch. I already compared the two branches but do not see any difference, apart from adding a new UWP project z. I just tested what happens if I remove project z and then it works without warnings. Project z is a UWP class library. Project z also contains the DefaultLanguage block. Project z contains a rResource file, which contains only binary files which need to be distributed, could the problem be that this has no language membership? How would I add one?

Any idea why it is not picking this up? I also looked at the other UWP projects in the solution, they all contain the DefaultLanguage block.

Comment: I want to know if your main project adds reference to this UWP library, could you build your project successfully?

Comment: Yes project x has a reference to the library project z, the project builds but throws a warning. If I remove the reference to z it builds without the warning.

Comment: For now, according to your description, it's hard to say where the issue is. What's your project's target/min version? And what's the visual studio version?  If possible, please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis.

Comment: I don't think the questions are exact duplicates, but when you stumbled upon this question, you may also be interested in the answers for this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360272/how-can-i-set-default-language-of-uwp-app/