# How can i set default language of UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I have 2 languages. en-US and ru-Ru

[image]
[image]

When i set Default Language to ru-RU i got the error:

> PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'ru-ru,en-us'
>   but no resources found for default language(s): 'ru-RU'. Change the
>   default language or qualify resources with the default language.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please check if the packagemanifest file `Language` line is `<Resource Language="x-generate" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue:
`Resources found for language(s) 'nl-be,en-us' but no resources found for default language(s): 'nl-be,en-us'`. So it complains about finding resources, it doesn't find. It may not be the result of the same root cause as OP's problem, but I want to share my *fix*, that's why I'll explain my search path of how I *fixed* it below. Maybe you can find a solution for your specific situation in any of these steps. To start: My project has as default language `nl-BE` in its appxmanifest.

My search led me to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/specify-default-resources-installed. After trying this, I discovered the warning didn't show up when I build as `Release` instead of `Debug`. In the article above, they mentioned `<ProjectFolder>\obj\<ReleaseConfiguration folder>\priconfig.xml` so I went there and took a look.

In this folder there are all these `resource*.resfile`s. I checked each one of them. I couldn't find any issues (they all contained resources for both languages (nl-BE and en-US)). That is, when I look in `Release`. However, when I looked in the `Debug` counterpart, I found a `resources.en-us.resfiles` file. There was no `nl-be` counterpart and it contained a single resource `obj\x64\Debug\FxResources.System.Text.Json.SR.resw`. As far as I know, these are resources for code analyzers (not something I actively added to my project) and there is no `nl-be` counterpart.

My project has as default language `nl-BE` in its appxmanifest. Setting `<qualifier name="Language" value="nl-BE" />` in `priconfig.default.xml` of course still didn't fix the warning in `Debug` (there are no nl-BE FxResources), but changing the default language in the appxmanifest and `priconfig.default.xml` to `en-US` did fix the warnings in `Debug`. The `resources.en-us.resfiles` file doesn't appear anymore and the resource `FxResources.System.Text.Json.SR.resw` is added to the `resources.resfile`. After discovering all this, I reverted my project back to `nl-BE` and don't bother anymore with the warning.

TL;DR: It only happens because of the code analyzers, which are not included in `Release`.